# What is the best way to use HTTPS in asp .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have published an asp.net core project(a website which made by asp.net core MVC) on a server(windows server 2018) and it works well for a long time.

And also, it used the HTTP all the time. As we know, now google suggest upgrade HTTP to HTTPS for more safely. So I wanna to upgrade it also.

I have applied for an SSL certificate yet and I found several ways to use HTTPS in asp.net core, such as:

1. The official way by adding so many codes in code-behind:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
2. By using PowerShell and edit some code in code-behind:
   https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2018/07/05/aspnetcore-ssl.html
3. By using some Nuget Package:
   https://dzone.com/articles/enforce-ssl-and-use-hsts-in-net-core20-net-core-se
4. Just configure it in visual studio:
   https://wildermuth.com/2016/10/26/Testing-SSL-in-ASP-NET-Core

But I tried all the way above and failed. Now I am crazy because there are so many ways and I don't know which one is right.

What's more, if all ways above can achieve it, then what's the difference between them and what's the advantage and disadvantage of them?

I am a beginner in web development and I have never been in touch with the HTTPS.

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, the binding is not the concern of your application code itself but rather of the server / host. Which brings the question: How is your application hosted? Is it IIS? Kestrel?

Comment: Can you explain more? Is HTTPS not working or both HTTP and HTTPS works?

Comment: @haim770 By IIS.

Comment: The HTTPS not working. I want to upgrade the HTTP to HTTPS and the website will not use HTTP any more.

Comment: @haim770 But why even the tutorial of microsoft tell us edit the code in code-behind?

Comment: @102425074 The tutorials you mentioned are about *enforcing* HTTPS (either using HSTS or automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS) and not about *enabling* it. To do so, you must install the certificate (along with the associated private key, usually in the form of a PFX file) in IIS Manager. See https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm for example. TL;DR: First you install the certificate, then you can enforce using it

Comment: OK, according to your tutorial it works. But it is so strange that I can access the website in the server by typing the URL while in my computer it throws an error that the connection refused to connect.@haim770

Comment: What's more, there is one more question: As you said enforcing HTTPS, why not upgrade all the HTTP to HTTPS in the website directly but only redirect it?@haim770

Comment: @102425074 **1.** You need to make sure that the certificate is correctly installed, and that's beyond the scope of this discussion (try https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for example). **2.** There is no way to automatically "upgrade" a connection from HTTP to HTTPS as they're fundamentally different and usually bound to different TCP ports (80 vs. 443), among other reasons.

Comment: @haim770 I did as you said in the URL and it gave me an Overall Rating C, also has any other information. It seems has correctly installed.

Comment: @haim770 I know what's wrong with my website now. I deleted the HTTP binding and only bind the HTTPS so it failed. I bound the HTTP and enforcing the HTTP to HTTPS, now it works.

Comment: @haim770 Here is the last question:Which status code should I use when I Redirect HTTP to HTTPS? The example of Microsoft is using 307/308, but I googled and found someone said should use the 301 best.

Comment: @102425074 From what I experienced, it's 301. I'm unaware of any spec that details otherwise then I assume it can be regarded as an implementation detail as long as the browser does redirect.

Comment: @haim770 Yes, we know the browser will redirect both, but I have heard yet the status code will affect the SEO of the website. Aha

Comment: @102425074 You can use Let's Encrypt and it is free. Basically hosting provider support it and you can easily setup it through control panel.